# how to select attachment in android: similar to email

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app. It's not an email app. But it has a feature similar to email, where a user may select to send an attachment along with a message. When I click to add attachment on my gmail, for example, I get the option to attach anything such as video, music, picture, file, etc. Has anyone ever build such an intent and unmarshalled the data **and** don't mind sharing their expertise?

**edit**

I am not able to get the multiple mime types in. I need the intent to be able to get video or image or music:

```
public void onGetAttachmentClicked(View view) {
    Intent attachment = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    attachment.setType("image/*,video/*,audio/*");
    startActivityForResult(attachment, ATTACHMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Right now it only launches the `Photos` or `Gallery` app. It does not load for audio, whereas the Gmail app attachment button does.

**I think I got it, but I can't say 100% yet** so I will reward @CommonsWare after testing

```
  public void onGetAttachmentClicked(View view) {
    Intent attachment = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    attachment.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(attachment, "Pick Attachment"),
            ATTACHMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: What does "build such an intent and unmarshalled the data" mean?

Comment: Basically an intent that launches a "grid dialog" (so to speak) from which I can choose the correct application such as `gallery` or `photos` or `music`. I have seen app that does it. I am doing some research on the internet. since I haven't found it yet, I ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get content based on MIME type, use [an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) with `startActivityForResult()`. The `Uri` delivered to your `onActivityResult()` method will point to the piece of content that the user chose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why, but I am getting stuck. I am editing my post to show what I have so far. I want the user to be able to select image or video or music. So far I only have the one for image. I am reading on setting multiple mime type but it's not working. So I am going to edit my post. Maybe you can help me a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simulate a html form(by assembling http header, parameters), and post your attachment to your server likes picking a file then submit the form